# String replace with integer not working

Tags: java, string, replace, integer, replaceall

I have been working on some Java code and I came across a really weird error, Im trying to replace a piece of string with an Integer.
Added all kinds of debugs but I cant seem to find it out.

```
private void executeMsg() {
    value = value.replaceAll("(&([a-f0-9]))", "§$2");

    String border = tostiuhc.getWorldManager().getBorderSize() - tostiuhc.getShrinksize() + "";
    String time = tostiuhc.getPhase().getMinutes() + "";

    System.out.println("BORDER: " + border);
    System.out.println("TIME: " + time);

    value = value.replace("-border-", border + "");
    value = value.replace("-time-", time + "");

    tostiuhc.broadcast(value + " " + time);
}
```

As you can see, I create new String called 'time' and print it out 'TIME: value'.
The original string that I'm changing is: The event is now -time- minutes in!

[image]

[image]

The problem here is that System.out.println("TIME:") shows the correct value, but the .replace just DOESNT work.
I cant get my head around this, anyone has any idea?

Comment: The quoted output is useless, as it doesn't ever include outputting `value` after the `replace`. What do you see when you debug this? What *is* `value`? Looks like an instance field, meaning that `-time-` won't be present the second time you do this. This really just calls for basic debugging.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to replace a string with an int?

Comment: @AndreasDM Right here: value = value.replace("-time-", time + ""); I changed it to a String already.

Comment: And what is the initial value of `value`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the tostiuhc.broadcast(value + " " + time); is "The event is now 0 minutes in! 0"

Comment: @Tom "The event is now -time- minutes in!"

Comment: @Harm-Jan: Can you add a `System.out.println(value);` just before the replace?  What does it print?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The replace only works on the first execution. After that, `value` no longer contains `-time-`. As a solution, you can use a temporary variable to do your replacement:

```
String displayValue = value.replace("-time-", time + "");
```

Comment: oh, so `value` is a global variable?  I think you might be right! Curious to see if OP confirms.

Comment: @sstan How could it not be? Besides, look at the screenshot in the original post.

Comment: And to make it even better, he should pass the String to the methos as an argument :D.

Comment: You sir, deserve a big cookie, I have been hitting my head for so long on this. It's so funny to see now, thank you so much for the help! I will accept this answer asap.

Comment: @shmosel oh so intelligent solution..it saved my time! Thank you.